# Uploading files to the wrong related list

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, files, contentdocument

I am trying to upload files to one record while displaying the CombinedAttachments related lists for multiple records. No matter which related list I use to upload files, they always get attached to the first record. I have tried the AttachedContentDocuments related list which will add the file to every record which is not what I want either.

[image]

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Loan_Document__c" extensions="FLLC_LoanDocCreationWizard_Uploader" title="Loan Doc Creation Wizard - Uploader" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:pageblock title="Upload Attachments for your Application Documents" rendered="{!NOT(is_error)}" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="Done();" class="btn"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:repeat value="{!doc_classes}" var="d">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!d.title}" columns="1">
                <apex:relatedList subject="{!d.doc.id}" list="CombinedAttachments"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageblock>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!Done}" name="Done"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller

```
for (Loan_Document__c ld : new_app_docs) {
    DocWithTitle temp = new DocWithTitle();
    temp.doc = ld;
    temp.title = getTitle(ld);
    doc_classes.add(temp);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error,temp.doc.Id);
}
```

The debug logs show different Ids.

One note that might not be related is that this previously worked in Classic when there were the New Note and Attach File buttons instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just making my own tables instead of using Related Lists.